# date assignment from array list to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

I have an Array List  myData which  holds value like this

```
[20-01-2018,10-01-2018, 20-02-2018, TASk2, 11-02-2018, 21-03-2018, TASK3, 15-03-2018, 19-04-2018]
```

am assigning that  values to a javascript variable

```
var start = new Date(<%=myData.get(1)%>);
```

`alert(start)`  gives   output as

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 05:29:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

but when i print  `myData.get(1)`  gives

```
10-01-2018
```

i want the start variable to hold the date value `10-01-2018` alone
can any one tell me where am i wrong.

I have made below modifications.Added a java script function to format the date 
as required by me and return it.

step. 1 Iterate the arraylist
      2. assign value as argument  to a java script function to format it

> start=formatMyDate('<%=pertData.get(loopcount+1)%>');
>   end=  formatMyDate('<%=pertData.get(loopcount+2)');

```
function formatMyDate(myday)
{         

    alert("entered value"+myday);

    var tday = new Date(myday);

    alert("processing on value"+tday);  
    alert(typeof tday);

    var dd = tday.getDate();
    var mm = tday.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = tday.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10){
       mm='0'+mm;
    } 

    var ret = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

    alert("left value"+ret); 

    return ret;       
}
```

Now for some  values it works and  for some it does'nt and gives Invalid date

Sample ouput after running JScript

entered value20-02-2018
processing on valueInvalid Date

Comment: Is this question for Java or JavaScript?

Comment: `new Date(<%=myData.get(1)%>);` - creates a date object by parsing the string

Comment: Hi Pranav,The value am fetching from arraylist I tried converting it  into a string in two ways .One using to sTring method ...Now i have rewritten entire thing in another way but still its not working properly

Comment: [20-01-2018,10-01-2018, 20-02-2018, TASk2, ....] Is not valid array data. You can wrap each array element with the quote to make sure they are in string format.

Comment: Hi Fadhly  Thats the ouput i get after i print the arraylist in java.It holds objects am typecasting it into string later

Answer (score 0):

What about simply:

```
const start = myData.get(1);
```

or

```
const start = myData[1];
```

?

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: I cant use const. This variable keeps one over wirting as i  iterate the array list and assign . I have made some more changes but this works in a quiet weird way

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not meet the correct format for the string you hand in when calling

```
var tday = new Date(myday);
```

Please have a look at this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp). There you can see which format your string must have to receive a valid date object. Which means in your case, that it was useless to push the string through this conversion process using `new Date()`. Better get your year, month and day directly:

```
let start = myData[1];

const dd = start.substring(0,2);
const mm = start.substring(3,5);
const yyyy = start.substring(6,10);

const ret = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

alert("left value: " + ret);

return ret;
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.